# Action Editor : merging multiple animated armatures?

Tags: animation, armature

I've animated my model using armatures, and in the editor view I see that I've created 46 bones. Each bone responsible for another part of the plant. Someone told me to use Action Editor. When I open Action Editor, I see that there's 46 actions in my file!!! instead of say 1, that has all the information.

This is how it should look, taken from a tutorial in youtube called

> Blender 3d Tutorial - Animation, How to Merge Actions to Single Sequence by VscorpianC

All the bones in one Action Editor place:
[image]

This is how it looks in my workspace:

[image]

How can the bones be merged into one action?? Is it possible? How can this be done?

Comment: To clarify you have 46 one bone armature objects, each with an action animating one stalk of your plant,  that you want to merge into one 46 bone armature, with one action, animating one plant (ie all the stalks are merged into one mesh?

Comment: Yes! Well A good soul send me this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb152Qncn2s, and I'm on my way of implementing it.

Comment: @batFINGER I did exactly as the tutorial above said, and placed manually all the bones into one action, by connecting it to the action and "locRot" locking the rotation. QUESTION: should I now bake the action? or export as usual to .fbx that will go into Unity3d? p.s when baking the action the whole model got distorted.